# Heroku migrations refuse being made

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I deployed a django rest application on Heroku but I noticed when I went to the api route, I see a `no such table` error. I figured I needed to do

1. heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
2. heroku run python manage.py migrate
3. heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser

Which I actually did, I got a lot of OK from running those migrations but then when I decided to create a super user, it says I have 20 unapplied migrations even though I just run the migrate command and got plenty of OKs

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using SQLite as your database, take note that Heroku is ephemeral any user data will not persist on disk. Every time your instance restart all data except in your repo are wiped out. You should use other DB like Postgres which Heroku also offer as a managed service.

Comment: I had forgotten about that, thanks. Once I switched to postgres it all got fixed